# Como carregar texto de um componente em outro (Angular)

Tags: angular, textarea

Estou tentando carregar o texto de um campo e quero reutilizar esse texto no carregamento de um ConfirmDialogComponent.

Este texto aqui

[image: Este Texto aqui]

Deve vir nesse DialogComponent

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o código do DialogComponent

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
  width: '500px',
  data: {
    textArea: 'Observação'
  }
});
```

Não sei qual atributo modificar, tentei adicionar

*text: 'Texto teste'*

no data ou tentar modificar o textArea colocando

*textArea: {title: 'Observação', text: 'texto teste'}*

Tinha feito pesquisa no Google mas não achei como alterar esse textArea dentro do ConfirmDialog

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, tive que alterar o ConfirmDialogComponent para conseguir adicionar um "value" dentro do textArea.

```
export class ConfirmDialogComponent {
  confirmar = 'Confirmar';
  cancelar = 'Cancelar';
  no = 'Não';
  yesNoCancel = false;
  date;
  dateTime = new Date().getTime();
  text;
  textArea;
  value;
  okBtn = false;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    if (this.data.textoBotoes === 'SimNao') {
      this.confirmar = 'Sim';
      this.cancelar = 'Não';
    } else if (this.data.yesNoCancel) {
      this.confirmar = 'Sim';
      this.yesNoCancel = true;
    } else if (this.data.date) {
      this.date = this.data.date;
    } else if (this.data.text) {
      this.text = this.data.text;
    } else if (this.data.textArea) {
      this.textArea = this.data.textArea;
    } else if (this.data.textoBotoes === 'Ok') {
      this.okBtn = true;
      this.cancelar = 'Ok';
    }// Precisei acidionar essa validação abaixo para conseguir alterar o "value" do componente
    if (data.value) {
      this.value = data.value;
    }
  }
}
```

E entao o construtor dele ficou assim:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
  width: '500px',
  data: {
    textArea: 'Observação',
    value: 'texto teste'
  }
});
```

E agora é possível alterar o valor do campo textArea!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar um service e importar em ambos os componentes, no service criar uma variável para receber o valor do campo e atribuir o valor da variável do service ao value do textarea do modal.

Assim o textarea vai ter o mesmo valor do campo do outro componente!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).